# how to start smarty php and which technology should i use or download?

Tags: php, smarty

i do not know how to install and works smarty php. someone please guide me. please tel me briefly how to install and what software i need to download and all because am a newbie for this technology. I tried this in normal php but i cannot do that.

Comment: http://www.smarty.net/quick_install try to read and understand

Answer (score 0):

You don't need any special installation for the `smarty`. You are just going to require a file named as `Smarty.class.php`

I recommend you to have a look over [Smarty Official Page which tells about  Installation](http://www.smarty.net/docsv2/en/installing.smarty.basic)

Here is a quick example given over there

```
<?php
// NOTE: Smarty has a capital 'S'
require_once('Smarty.class.php');   #This is the file you need to require
$smarty = new Smarty();
?>
```

**Note :**

1. You need to give the exact path that you extracted the Smarty inside your  project folder.
2. If you are using on linux system then you give read permission to the folder which Smarty is installed.